# At the rate symbol not working for email id in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I am trying to default an email id called "test@test.com" to a field "userEmailId" in JOLT but it is not working.  Any idea on what wrong I am doing and what changes I need to do in my JOLT spec to get the email id?

Right now in the spec I have removed the "@" symbol.

Below is what I tried-

```
"#test@test.com":"IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId"
```

Input JSON-

```
{
    "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
        "MsgData": {
            "Transaction": {
                "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
                    "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1,
                    "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "PeggyMeincke@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "Zachary",
                    "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "Engels",
                    "WG_DELIVER_TO": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                    "PO_ID": 25052,
                    "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                    "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                    "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                    "PO_DT": "2020-01-24",
                    "DB_NUMBER_BU": "",
                    "DESCR_BU": "OhioFarmersInsuranceCo",
                    "ADDRESS1_BU": "WESTFIELDCOMPANIES",
                    "ADDRESS2_BU": "HOMEOFFICE",
                    "ADDRESS3_BU": "1PARKCIRCLE",
                    "ADDRESS4_BU": "",
                    "CITY_BU": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
                    "STATE_BU": "OH",
                    "POSTAL_BU": "44251-5001",
                    "COUNTRY_BU": "USA",
                    "ADDRESS1_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS2_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS3_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS4_BILL": "",
                    "CITY_BILL": "",
                    "STATE_BILL": "",
                    "POSTAL_BILL": "",
                    "COUNTRY_BILL": "",
                    "CURRENCY_CD": "USD",
                    "TAX_EXEMPT_ID": "",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_VNDR": "",
                    "NAME1_VNDR": "AMAZONCAPITALSERVICESINC",
                    "ADDRESS1_VNDR": "410TERRYAVEN",
                    "ADDRESS2_VNDR": "",
                    "ADDRESS3_VNDR": "",
                    "ADDRESS4_VNDR": "",
                    "CITY_VNDR": "SEATTLE",
                    "STATE_VNDR": "WA",
                    "POSTAL_VNDR": 98109,
                    "COUNTRY_VNDR": "USA",
                    "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "NET30",
                    "DESCR50_PAY": "Net30",
                    "BUYER_ID": 1083,
                    "PO_AMT_TTL": 14.99,
                    "TEXT254_CC1": "",
                    "TEXT254_CC2": "",
                    "VNDR_UPN_FLG": "N",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_VNDRGLN": "",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_BILLTO": "",
                    "ATTN_TO": "ZacharyEngels",
                    "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
                        "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
                        "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "FSSUP",
                        "WG_ITEM_TYPE": 0,
                        "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
                        "WG_DEPT_ID": 30400,
                        "WG_PRODUCT": "",
                        "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                        "PO_ID": 25052,
                        "WG_ASSET_GROUP": "",
                        "WG_CAPITALIZE": "NO",
                        "WG_PROFILE_ID": "",
                        "WG_SPLIT_TYPE": 1,
                        "WG_ASSET_LOC": "HOME",
                        "WG_PROJECT": "",
                        "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                        "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                        "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                        "LINE_NBR": 1,
                        "INV_ITEM_ID": "",
                        "DESCR254_MIXED": "147-1518156-3620845,1GreenMountainCoffeeRoastersCaramelVanillaCreamKeurigSingle-ServeK-CupPods,LightRoastCoffee,32Count",
                        "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "EA",
                        "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
                        "VNDR_CATALOG_ID": "",
                        "MFG_ID": "",
                        "MFG_ITM_ID": 5000196305,
                        "CNTRCT_ID": "",
                        "VERSION_NBR": 0,
                        "CNTRCT_LINE_NBR": 0,
                        "CAT_LINE_NBR": 0,
                        "RELEASE_NBR": 0,
                        "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
                        "UPN_ID": "",
                        "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
                            "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 0,
                            "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "OFIC",
                            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                            "PO_ID": 25052,
                            "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                            "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                            "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                            "LINE_NBR": 1,
                            "SCHED_NBR": 1,
                            "DUE_DT": "2020-01-29",
                            "SHIPTO_ID": "OFIC",
                            "DESCR_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
                            "ADDRESS1_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
                            "ADDRESS2_SHIPTO": "1PARKCIRCLE",
                            "ADDRESS3_SHIPTO": "POBOX5001",
                            "ADDRESS4_SHIPTO": "",
                            "CITY_SHIPTO": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
                            "STATE_SHIPTO": "OH",
                            "POSTAL_SHIPTO": "44251-5001",
                            "COUNTRY_SHIPTO": "USA",
                            "PRICE_PO": 14.99,
                            "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
                            "QTY_PO": 1,
                            "SHIP_TYPE_ID": "BEST_WAY",
                            "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
                            "ATTN_TO": "",
                            "STD_ID_NUM_SHIPTO": ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JOLT Spec-

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "#integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
            "#referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
            "#additionalInfo": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.additionalInfo",
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "PO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
                            "#APPROVED": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
                            "PO_AMT_TTL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
                            "#testtest.com": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId",
                            "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                            "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
                            "WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
                            "#OFIC": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
                            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
                            "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
                            "#1": [
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                            ],
                            "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
                            "CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
                            "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
                            "VENDOR_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
                            "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
                            "#2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
                            "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
                            "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
                            "@CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
                            "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
                          
                            "*": {
                                "WG_REQ_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                                "#STANDARD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                                "LINE_NBR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                                "MFG_ITM_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                                "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                                    "#name4": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                                    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                                },
                                "WG_DEPT_ID": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                                    "#name3": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                                    "#Westfield Department": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PRODUCT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].value",
                                    "#name6": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].type",
                                    "#Product/Parcel": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PROJECT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].value",
                                    "#name5": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].type",
                                    "#Project Code": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].name"
                                },
                                "WG_ASSET_GROUP": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].value",
                                    "#name10": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].type",
                                    "#Asset Group": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].name"
                                },
                                "WG_CAPITALIZE": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].value",
                                    "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].type",
                                    "#Capitalize": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PROFILE_ID": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].value",
                                    "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].type",
                                    "#Profile Id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].name"
                                },
                                "WG_ASSET_LOC": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].value",
                                    "#name2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].type",
                                    "#Business Unit": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].name"
                                },
                                "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].value",
                                    "#name7": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].type",
                                    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].name"
                                },
                                "*": {
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                                    "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                                    "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                                    "SHIPTO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                                    "DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                                    "@DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                                    "PRICE_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                                    "QTY_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                                    "#1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    
    {
        "operation": "cardinality",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "status": "ONE",
                            "poHeader": {
                                "*": "ONE",
                                "checkoutBuyer":{
                                    "userEmailId": "ONE"
                                },
                                "company": {
                                    "*": "ONE"
                                }
                            },
                            "items": {
                                "item": {
                                    "costingSplitType": "ONE",
                                    "validCombinations": {
                                        "itemDetails": {
                                            "validRules": {
                                                "field": {
                                                    "id": "ONE",
                                                    "type": "ONE",
                                                    "name": "ONE",
                                                    "value": "ONE"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Output-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape for **`@`** character as a special one by using ***double backslashes*** such as

```json
"#test\\@test.com": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.
poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId",
```